# F2 addon suddenly doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: add-on

I was using the F2 addon, but all of the sudden, it just spit out an error, anytime I have two Edge loops, I want to connect with the F key. The error is the following:

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Did you try removing doubles? There's a possibility that this is caused because of multiple vertices at the same position.

Comment: The key error suggests an issue with `loop[uv_layer]` where `uv_layer` is the key.  Is there a chance it's `None`.  Does mesh have a UVMap?  Try the help button on the addons expanded info panel in prefs.